# OAuth - preventing a multiple users using the same credentials

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0

Scenario: I am creating an application which uses OAuth for authentication and I want to try and limit a user sharing their credentials with colleagues (we charge per seat).  The only way I could think of this was to store the IP with the token (although I'm aware multiple users from a single client could be on the same IP).

Is there a standard way of doing this in OAuth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not via any feature specific to OAuth. A valid user that logs on from the office or from home will have a different IP address. How would you distinguish that from another user that has someone else their credentials?

The only way I see to make this work is require two-factor authentication. It's much less likely your users will be prepared to share for example their phone to use your application.

Just make sure your application adds enough value that your users will want their own account and not share credentials.

Comment: I was thinking of throttling their API requests (not related to OAuth) by user and IP address, that wouldn't absolutely stop credential sharing but it would make it impossible/unusable for many concurrent users using the same credentials.  Interestingly, Spotify are incredibly good at restricting their music streaming to one user at a time, perhaps by IP, I'm unsure.

Comment: I suppose throttling by user and IP address may make it harder to share credentials, but if your site is popular, you'll run into valid users being  throttled. I would think 2FA makes more sense in your situation.

Comment: We are selling B2B so it makes credential sharing less likely to occur.  But, yes even B2B solutions will at some point need to negotiate this.